# Finding sum of x^k from k= 0 to n in O(logn) time

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o

So my question is how to do this in C more specifically. I'm aware that O(logn) usually means that we'll be using recursion by somehow splitting one of the parameters.

What I'm trying to achieve is the sum of k = 0 to n of x<sup>n</sup>.
for example exponent_sum(x, n) would be the parameters in this case.

Then,

`exponent_sum(4, 4)` would be 4<sup>0</sup> + 4<sup>1</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>4</sup> = 341.

I'm not sure where to start. Some hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: compute something else as a byproduct. You'll need it to make the recursion work.

Comment: How would you solve the problem on paper?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to look at the sum is as a number in base x consisting of all 1s.

For e.g, 4<sup>4</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>1</sup> + 4<sup>0</sup> is 11111 in base 4.

In any base, a string of 1s is going to be equal to 1 followed by a string of the same number of 0s, minus 1, divided by the base minus 1.

For e.g:

- in base 10: (1000 - 1) / 9 = 999 / 9 = 111
- in base 16: (0x10000 - 1) / 0xF = 0xFFFF / 0xF = 0x1111
- in base 8: (0100 - 1) / 7 = 077 / 7 = 011

etc

So put these together and we can generalize that

exponent_sum(x, n) = (x <sup>(n + 1)</sup> - 1) / (x - 1)

For example, exponent_sum(4, 4) = (4<sup>5</sup> - 1) / 3 = 1023 / 3 = 341

So the big O complexity for it will be the same as for computing x<sup>n</sup>

Comment: This is a pretty cool proof of the geometric series. Never seen this one before.

Comment: Agreed with the top comment. I've never thought of it this way. Thank you, this helped me tons.

Comment: It is very neat, but also suffers because it relies on the claim about a string of k 1s being equal to 1 followed by k 0s, minus 1, then divided by the base minus 1. That's not a trivial claim and not obvious, and the work to prove it if you don't know it is generally worse than the simpler equation rearranging for the standard solution.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add another proof for the sake of completeness:

s = 1 + x<sup>1</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sup>n</sup>

Then

xs = x(1 + x<sup>1</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sup>n</sup>) = x<sup>1</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sup>n</sup> + x<sup>n+1</sup> = s - 1 + x<sup>n+1</sup>

Solving for s

(x - 1)s = x<sup>n+1</sup> - 1,

s = (x<sup>n+1</sup> - 1)/(x - 1)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see the solution is like this: suppose the sum is `S` written as

```
S = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^k
```

Then if we multiply both sides of it by `x` we get

```
S*x = x * (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^k)
    = x + x^2 + ... + x^k + x^(k+1)
```

then add 1 to both sides

```
S*x + 1 = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^k + x^(k+1)
        = (1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^k) + x^(k+1)
        = S + x^(k+1)
```

which means

```
S*x - S = x^(k+1) - 1
S*(x - 1) = x^(k+1) - 1
```

so

```
S = (x^(k+1) - 1) / (x - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the theory Of geometric progression. where

```
sum = (first-term(pow(common-ratio,number-of-terms)-1))/(common-ratio-1);
here first-term is obviously 1;
Common-ratio= number itself;
number-of-terms=number+1;
```

But common-ratio should be greater than 1;
For

```
Common-ratio=1;
Sum=number*number-of-terms.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the sum directly, without using the geometric progression formula. This has the advantage that no division is required (which is necessary if, for example, you want to adapt the code to return the result modulo some large number).

Letting S(k) to be the sum x^0 + ... + x^{k-1}, it satisfies these recurrence relations:

```
S(1)    = 1
S(2n)   = S(n) * (1 + x^n)
S(2n+1) = S(n) * (1 + x^n) + x^{2n}
```

Using these, the only difficulty is arranging to keep a running value of `xp` to use as x^n. Otherwise the algorithm is very similar to a bottom-up implementation of exponentiation by squaring.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t exponent_sum(int64_t x, int64_t k) {
    int64_t r = 0, xp = 1;
    for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
        r *= 1 + xp;
        xp *= xp;
        if (((k + 1) >> i) & 1) {
            r += xp;
            xp *= x;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        printf("4^0 + 4^1 + ... + 4^%d = %" PRId64 "\n", k, exponent_sum(4, k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```